# Why are EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE "implementation defined"?

Tags: c

If you are supposed to return 0 from main, and EXIT_SUCCESS is "implementation defined", and it literally says that [it is not required to be 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status), then what is the point of it if you can't rely on it being the correct value? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you use those macros, it doesn't matter what values they are, it'll Just Work.

Comment: @Shawn `If you use those macros, it doesn't matter what values they are, it'll Just Work. ` - Until you write a bash or perl script that needs to check the return value of that program, then you crawl up into a ball and cry due to potential future portability issues.

Comment: @Dmitry I'd expect `if somecmd; then echo yay; else echo error; fi` in a shell to work no matter the values of `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` on that system.

Comment: @Shawn How is that possible when as far as I am aware, bash is required to treat 0 as success in if statements regardless of what `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined as in `stdlib.h` on the particular system. Wouldn't returning 0 be less likely to cause incompatibility? It also avoids issues where `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE` might collide with other return values(it's expensive to tell what return values you can return if you don't know what success nor failure mean in your program). The whole thing makes no sense, only the author of the program can specify what successes/failures/neither/both mean.

Comment: @Dmitry Any shell written to run on this hypothetical OS where `EXIT_SUCCESS` is non-0 would of course be aware of that and handle that case appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning the integer `n` from `main` (if `main` has an `int` return value) is equivalent to calling exit(n) -- 5.1.2.2.3.1 in the standard. `exit` is defined such that both `exit(0)` and `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` are both implementation-defined forms of the status successful termination -- 7.20.4.3.5 in the standard.

So returning 0 (or having no return and dropping off the end of main) cause a "successful" termination of a program.

I don't think the standard guarantees that `return EXIT_SUCCESS` and `return 0` are exactly equivalent as returns from main, but it's definitely ok to `return 0` from main and expect your OS to treat this as a successful termination of your program, no matter what `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined as.

Note that websites like cppreference.com are not the best source of information about the C standard, even if they're mostly accurate -- it's much better to go to the actual standard (or at least one of the freely available committee drafts if the official standard is paywalled) and read what it says.

Comment: And, on the other side, returning `EXIT_FAILURE` from the initial call to `main()`, or passing that value to `exit()`, produces a program termination that the host OS will interpret as failure.  And on the third side *the C programming language* does not specify how the host OS will interpret other arguments to `exit()`, but the host OS will certainly have ideas about that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a piece of retro-fitted standardisation.

At point of Standardisation (and `EXIT_SUCCESS` was defined then) it makes sense to permit the common practice (`return 0;`) but also to have constants and unnecessary to define that the constant is necessarily the common value. Though it usually is.

Having constants is well-aligned to a specific aim of Standardisation which was to make it possible to write portable C programs more easily.

Both `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` indicate successful program execution to the host environment. Though `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not required to be zero.

So it's wrong to say *you can't rely in it being the correct value* because it is guaranteed to be **one of** the correct values for indicating successful execution.

One of the one or more correct values at least one being `0`.
I'm not aware of any platform where it isn't `0`.

Remember C had diversified onto a number of platforms when it was finally Standardised and by then almost universal practice was that the return value of `0` meant success following the convention that return codes are error-codes and `0` being logical 'false' means 'no error'.

However given the aim of Standardisation was to increase portability it makes sense to provide for implementation defined constants in a critical step of interaction with the host-environment - termination.

I don't know if the constants were introduced during standardisation or included from a contributing implementation.

Remember it's not defined what the Host Environment does with the return value. Yes, common practice is that it's value is returned to the script or process that initiated program execution. But it could be mapped. On a hosting platform that didn't use `0` for success that return value would have to be mapped to different value, quite possibly whatever `EXIT_SUCCESS` expands to.

It's a bit esoteric because I'm not aware of a platform where `EXIT_SUCCESS` isn't `0` but the committee was right that you can be have a well defined language by specifying behaviour not concrete value here.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to return 0 on UNIXy systems, sure.

Consider targeting an esoteric OS where successful return code is, say, 42, and errors are 222.

That OS's headers will define those constants to 42 and 222, and your program, correctly using `EXIT_SUCCESS`, won't return zero, a completely weird value to the esoteric OS.

As an additional data point, e.g. FreeBSD defines a variety of other exit codes in [`sysexits.h`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.3-RELEASE&format=html).

Comment: returning n from main is equivalent to calling `exit(n)` -- 5.1.2.2.3.1 in the standard. `exit` is defined such that both `exit(0)` and `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` are both implementation-defined forms of the status _successful termination_ -- 7.20.4.3.5 in the standard. So returning 0 (or having no return and dropping off the end of main) cause a "successful" termination of a program.

Comment: Even in UNIX, you can decide your program will `exit(10);` if it runs successfully.  As a convention the standard cannot enforce it.  returning 0 on success is just a converntion, as the operating system has no way to check the idea of the program of what is a successful termination.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are supposed to return 0 from main, and EXIT_SUCCESS is "implementation defined", and it literally says that it is not required to be 0, then what is the point of it if you can't rely on it being the correct value? Am I missing something?

You are missing the fact that more than one value can indicate a successful exit. A C implementation could define any non-negative value to indicate success, and it could define `EXIT_SUCCESS` to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

> it literally says that it is not required to be 0,

It literally says that because it depends on the operating system you are running on.  Some operating systems have different termination codes to be sent to the parent process in case of failure, so something that is operating system dependent cannot be ensured by a standard document.

On the other side, you can implement a command that returns 1 on success and 0 when it fails.  In that case you will receive (in linux/unix/posix) `EXIT_SUCCESS` when the program accually runs unsuccessfully, and `EXIT_FAILURE` when the program runs ok.  It is a convention, and as such, someones can follow it and someones cannot.  The C definition cannot state successfully that a program that returns successfully will do an `exit(0);` to indicate that to the caller program and `exit(1);` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are supposed to return 0 from main, and EXIT_SUCCESS is "implementation defined", and it literally says that it is not required to be 0, then what is the point of it if you can't rely on it being the correct value?

You are in no way required to return 0 from the initial call to `main()`, nor (equivalently) to call `exit(0)`.  *If* you terminate that way then the execution environment will be notified that the termination was successful, by that program's measure of success.  **As a separate matter**, if you terminate by returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` from the initial call to `main()` or by calling `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` then in that case too, the execution environment will be notified that the termination was successful, regardless of the value to which `EXIT_SUCCESS` expands.

> Am I missing something?

You are missing at least that

- You can rely on a conforming C implementation to behave the way the spec says it does.
- From the perspective of the language spec, the consumer of the program's exit code is the C language implementation, not the execution environment.  It is C's responsibility to respond to the program's exit code in a manner appropriate to its execution environment.
- there may be more than one exit code that indicates success to a particular C implementation.  On the flip side, the significance of exit codes other than 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE` is not defined by C:  such codes are not required (by C) to indicate failure conditions.

For all of those reasons, your conclusion that "you can't rely on [`EXIT_SUCCESS`] being the correct value" is completely unfounded.  On the contrary, you absolutely *can* rely on `EXIT_SUCCESS` being *a* correct value.

I suspect that your view is being influenced by details of particular C implementations and host environments with which you are familiar.  To understand C (or any programming language) semantics, it helps to distinguish carefully between the requirements and behavioral guarantees of the language itself on one hand, and those of the execution environment on the other.  For one thing, your programs' portability is improved by relying only on the former inasmuch as that is possible.